# Checking Button Property Values - BackgroundImage

Tags: c#

I am trying to check if an iamge is previously set on a button or not by checking its width property. If it is not set then I want to set the iamge, but I
am getting following error. I am new to C# so pardon me if it is too basic.

Error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

```
if (button1.BackgroundImage.Width == 0)  // Error on this line
{
    button1.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.SubmitButton; // Works fine if put out of conditon
}
else
{
    button1.BackgroundImage = null;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to check for null before you set to the submit button image. The updated code looks like:

```
if (button1.BackgroundImage == null || button1.BackgroundImage.Width == 0)  // Error on this line
{
    button1.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.SubmitButton; // Works fine if put out of conditon
}
else
{
    button1.BackgroundImage = null;
}
```

Hopefully that helps. Good luck!

Comment: no need to check the *width*, checking for *null* would be enough.

Comment: @ArinGhazarian Correct you are! Just trying to stick as closely as possible to the original code snippet.

Comment: Thanks. Else is basically to toggle on/off image.